# How to add google +1 button in android app

Tags: android, button, google-plus, google-api-client

I am having problem while implementing `Google +1` button in my android application.
I followed instruction on this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) and my activity is showing `g+` button successfully but after clicking on button, it is showing a progress bar on the button only, please tell me how +1 button works in android it should open a login internet or what? 
I am not implementing signin with google just +1 button in my app. Hhere is my code, this is part of my code so it is not that proper.

```
public class as {

    private static final String URL = "www.app.in";
    private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.product_details);
        setCurrentContext(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.googleplus);
        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).clearScopes()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnStart");
        mPlusClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
        if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this,
                            REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
        // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR
                && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        // Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        // .show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be signed in for this to work, but you do not have to have a sign in button on your app.

If it is enabled (you can click on it) then you are already signed in and I suggest you check that you have specified a valid url.

Your code looks different to mine (I use a GameHelperListener) but as long as you have followed the documentation accurately it should be fine.

If you want to see it work, just download an app that has a +1 button on it, and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Change url like

```
url="https://market.android.com/details?id=xxx.xxx.xxx";
```

Also implement methods 
`ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener and extends activity`